# How is getStorageAt() used?

Tags: get-storage-at

I have tested with eth.getStorageAt() and it shows what I think is 32 bytes of storage. But what is the point of this function? Are we meant to see unused space with it?

This is what I have:

```
> con
{
  abi: [{
  constant: true,
  inputs: [],
  name: "studentAge",
  outputs: [{...}],
  payable: false,
  stateMutability: "view",
  type: "function"
  }, {
  constant: false,
  inputs: [{...}],
  name: "setAge",
  outputs: [],
  payable: false,
  stateMutability: "nonpayable",
  type: "function"
  }, {
  anonymous: false,
  inputs: [{...}],
  name: "changedAge",
  type: "event"
 }],
 address: "0xa6b4017e8437ace3301f9751735e84836cfc0b21",
 transactionHash: null,
 allEvents: function(),
 changedAge: function(),
 setAge: function(),
 studentAge: function()
}
> eth.getStorageAt(con.address,0)
"0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002d"
> eth.getStorageAt(con.address,1)
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
>
```

Code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
contract CollegeAdmin {
uint public studentAge=18;
event changedAge(uint age);
function setAge(uint age) public { 
studentAge = age;
changedAge(age);
}
}
```

Comment: It's just a tool to see the contents of a smart contract's storage. It might be useful in debugging scenarios, particularly to inspect private state variables.

Comment: I guessed that was the purpose, but I have 2d in the storage - do I compare that to bytecode or something like that? Is the bytecode references by storageAt?

Comment: Apparently the value that's stored in slot 0 in your contract's storage is 0x2d (45). Without knowing your code, I don't know what variable that is or why that's the value. I'm not sure what you're asking about in terms of bytecode... `storageAt` just reads storage at the specified slot.

Comment: Code added - I also added an age using geth.

Comment: `studentAge` should be in slot 0. Does that answer your question? If not, what question do you still have?

Comment: That was it, I just tested. If you want to add an answer, I will accept your answer. How do we know when slot 1 is used? Do we have to calculate the storage area and then work out the sequence of bytes stored for the variables?

Comment: See https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/miscellaneous.html#layout-of-state-variables-in-storage.

Comment: If you add your answer, I will accept it. Then you get some credits.